# could not find kernel image casper vmlinuz while doing installation

Tags: server

trying to install `ubuntu-11.10-server-i386` on my desktop for which i downloaded `Universal-USB-Installer-1.8.6.8`  and followed the step as described on Ubuntu website.

I am using a pen drive to install it on my machine.When i started system it showed me following options

1. Run Ubuntu from pen drive
2. Install Ubuntu

I when tried to installed it on my desktop nothing happened and the installation option menu keep coming on some more checking i found out that it showing following error

```
could not find kernel image casper vmlinuz
```

after doing goggling i came across the following post could not find kernel image][1](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/error-could-not-find-kernel-image-linux/)

but cross verification showed that everything is fine in files installed on pen drive.i even checked the Md5 check-sum of downloaded iso image and that is correct.

Can any one help me to find what exactly is going wrong in the process

Answer (score 1):

There should be an option when you boot to "Check disc for defects". Select this option (on the machine onto which you are attempting to install), to see if perhaps the data on the USB flash drive are corrupt (which is possible even if the .iso image from which you wrote the USB flash drive is good). This can also identify problems with the machine's ability to access the installation medium properly, which is why it's best to do it on the machine you want to install on.

If that doesn't check out, then try writing the image to the USB flash drive again. If that doesn't work, try writing the image to the USB flash drive with [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) instead of the Universal USB Installer. If that doesn't work (or "Check disc for defects" did work originally on the USB flash drive), try a different USB flash drive, or try installing burning and booting a CD or DVD.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu server has no casper (to detect and mount root filesystem from non-optical media). There is a bug on the issue: [Installation from flash for ubuntu server 13.04 fails to mount CD/ISO](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/debian-installer/+bug/1169950). Consider to subscribe to the bug to raise its heat. ;)